# How to Modify Author Page for all Users?

Tags: author-template

I am going to create a user profile page for all users in my blog. I thought, it is better to modify the author page for all users.

```
<?php
if(is_author()) { 
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), apply_filters( 'themejunkie_author_bio_avatar_size', 60 ) ); ?>
<h3><?php the_author(); ?></h3>
<?php the_author_meta( 'description' );} ?>
```

I use above code in archive.php file.

Ex Author Page : mysite.com/author/username

Above link is worked for only authors. How I modify that page for all users even they have not published any post ( Even role is Subscriber).

Comment: Possibly duplicate to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982047/wordpress-create-profile-pages-for-users)

Comment: @Nilambar Thanks. :-) But, I don't want to use WordPress plugin for this. That is also very similar question. But that isn't what I ask. I want to change the author page for all users.

Comment: Link to your theme/site please. You want a single user profile page or a list of all users in an archive?

Answer (score 0):

To get the data of the user displayed on the current author archive page you can use:

```
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
$user_info = get_userdata( $author->ID );
```

More info on what is returned: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

From there you can use the user details you need:

```
<?php echo $user_info->user_firstname . ' ' . $user_info->user_lastname; ?>
```